# Elavon api: Can't enter credit card number

Tags: payment-gateway, payment

After redirect to https://api.convergepay.com/VirtualMerchant/process.do we can't enter credit card number. There is "Account Data:" field but it's "readonly". What we did wrong?
I tried to modify request but unsuccessfully. Also, all works fine in "test" mode. This error only for "live" mode.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2018-05-02/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D1%82%202018-05-02%2011-32-34.png

Comment: How can we help you with your code if we can't read your code? Please click edit on the question and add it before the downvotes begin.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Account Data (which is the CC# field) is disabled. You need to log into the Converge web app and enable it there. That will allow it to be populated, on that same page you can custom name any of the fields, including Account Data to Credit Card Num.